# Is there a way to set changing terminal emulator background images?

Tags: shell-script, debian, xfce, terminal-emulator, xfce4-terminal

Is there a way I can set it up so that my terminal emulator changes its background image every set time interval? Basically something like the accompanying image but for terminal background image (image is from desktop background image settings).
**OS:** Debian Bullseye with XFCE4
**Terminal Emulator:** XFCE Terminal

[image]

Or, alternatively, how can I change the terminal background image with CLI? I can then maybe create a script to do so myself.

Comment: Try setting a image as background and overwrite/symlink the image with another from a list of image after a time interval.

Answer (score 0):

The Xfce Terminal config file is `terminalrc`, and it should be buried somewhere in your home directory. On my Fedora system, it's in `~/.config/xfce4/terminal`. On Debian, it may be elsewhere; e.g. in `~/.config/Terminal`. If you can't find it, you may need to [edit preferences in Xfce Terminal for it to be created](https://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?p=498952&sid=13d364de9d686d58d619cff0a0ff6f34#p498952).

Once you've found it, you just need to change the `BackgroundImageFile=` line in that file. The background of all running Xfce Terminal instances should update immediately.